# "ORA-00942 table or view does not exist" exception in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

I am trying to access Oracle synonyms from my c# code. But it is throwing exception ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. I tried out all the possible ways that I could find but failed to achieve so. Can anyone suggest me how I can access synonyms?

Here's what I want to do:

```
        string retrieveData="select * from syn_empdetails";  //syn_empdetails is the synonym
        using (OracleConnection sqlcon =  new OracleConnection())  
        {
            sqlcon.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
                sqlcmd.CommandText = retrieveData;
                OracleDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}",dr.GetString(0),dr.GetString(1),dr.GetString(2),dr.GetString(3));
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                sqlcon.Close();
```

Please suggest how I can access this synonym.

Note: This query runs fine in sql developer. All the connections and schema are also fine.

Is this due to privilege issue or something else and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct schema. Can you try running your select from any other table in your schema just to be sure it is an issue with the SYNONYM and not the connection.

Comment: Yeah @phonetic_man, I've checked with the connection itself, but then no error is getting displayed. But error is being displayed when I am using the query

Comment: Are you able to query from any other table in the schema? Else, can you put the following query instead SELECT user FROM dual and check the result.

Comment: Yes I am able to do so from other tables in the schema

Comment: Does it have the appropriate grants for the connected user to see the table? That error will show up if you haven't granted select to the connected user. Make sure both the synonym and the underlying table are visible to the runtime user.

Comment: Do you have to explicitly tell the OracleCommand that its `CommandType = CommandType.Text`?

Comment: Yes @PeterM, that's what I am also thinking...Maybe it is due to grant priviledges.